# $N$ is a matrix such that $N^3=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a $3\times 3$ matrix  $N$ such that $N^3=0$, then which of the following are/is true?

1. $N$ has a non zero eigenvector
2. $N$ is similar to a diagonal matrix
3. $N$ has $3$ linearly independent eigenvector
4. $N$ is not similar to a diagonal matrix

Well, eigenvalues of $N$ are all zeroes and characteristic polynomial is $x^3=0$, clearly not diagonalizable. so only $1$ is true.

Comment: One of 2 and 4 has to be true....

Comment: I think you need to worry about if $N$ is the zero matrix or not.

Comment: But $N$ is nilpotent of degree 3, which (should) mean that $N^2 \neq 0$.

Comment: non-zero eigenvector is a pleonasm: eigenvectors are non-zero by definition

Comment: The body and title of the question give different information. Do we only have $N^3=0$, or do we also have that $N$ is nilpotent of degree $3$ (i.e. $N^2\ne0$)? If so, this should be added to the body of the question.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen yes, simply "eigenvector" would suffice. And joriki's question needs to be settled to answer that, because the $0$-matrix doesn't have any. I believe the original questioner "meant" $N^3 = 0, N^2 \neq 0$, but may not be aware how crucial the second bit is.

Comment: I am sorry, $N$ was not nilpotent in the question.

Comment: @DavidWheeler Actually sometimes 2 is true and sometimes 4 is true, thus neither 2 nor 4 are true statements...

Comment: @DavidWheeler: Surely the $0$-matrix does have (non-zero) eigenvectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Clearly not diagonalizable" is not correct; *if* we know that $N^2\neq 0$, then you are correct (that would imply that the *minimal* polynomial of $N$ is also $x^3$, and since it is not square free then $N$ is not diagonalizable). But just from knowing that $N$ has characteristic polynomial $x^3$, we do *not* know whether $N$ is diagonalizable or not. It could be diagonalizable. Explicitly, $N$ is diagonalizable if and only if it is the zero matrix; prove it!

As noted, you cannot have 2 and 4 *both* false, since they are negations of each other and the excluded middle applies here. And 2 and 3 are logically equivalent for a $3\times 3$ matrix.

If the question explicitly states that $N^2\neq 0$, then you know that 2 is false. If the question does not explicitly state so, then you don't.